# CSV Data Set Config Not Executing While Using under For Each Loop

Tags: jmeter

I am passing array of csv files . I need to iterate all the csv the files. But I am unable to execute the For Each Loop and passed the dynamic value in CSV Data Set Config file name. Please help me on that.

i am unable to execute the loop using jmeter variable as file name .

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> 1. **Configuration elements**
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler
> 5. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 7. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

Configuration elements are being initialized **before anything else** therefore you cannot use a variable reference as the "Filename" of the CSV Data Set Config because the variable will not be set at the time of the CSV Data Set Config initialization.

You can use [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) functions as alternatives for the CSV Data Set Config, JMeter Functions are being evaluated just at the moment JMeter reaches them while executing [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) so they're the most dynamic and can be parameterized easily.

So I would recommend going for [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/) plugin to read the CSV file names into a JMeter Variable and the aforementioned function(s) to fetch the data from the CSV files.

You can install Directory Listing Config using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]